# Why am I getting a overflow error using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, overflow

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxxx/PycharmProjects/Snake/Snake.py", line 138, in <module>
    pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(playSurface, blue, (pos[0], pos[1]), 10, 10)
OverflowError: signed short integer is greater than maximum

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is line 138:

```
pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(playSurface, blue, (pos[0], pos[1]), 10, 10)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: not sure what playSurface or blue are... but if not them, then your pos[0] or pos[1] have values that violate the acceptable input range.

Comment: playSurface is just that, it is a the player surface, initialised through pygame, and blue is the color blue also through pycharm. pos[0] and pos[1] are x and y co-ordinates. So how can I fix this?

Comment: `aacircle(surface, x, y, r, color)` from the documentation. The order of the arguments matters in Python. Your issue may come from this.

Comment: Thanks! I think that worked but now I have to fix another error...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing happen while implementing a slice-of-time improvement, but found the traceback did not accurately identify where the problem originated. After digging a little, the problem was resolved when speeds were resolved within calculable limits before populating rect.move().

Answer (score 0):

Pygame's `gfxdraw` module has different parameters for `aacircle` than `draw` has for `circle`.

[The official reference gives:](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html#pygame.gfxdraw.circle)

```
aacircle(surface, x, y, r, color) -> None
```

You want to rewrite your line as

```
pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(playSurface, (pos[0], pos[1]), 10, blue)
```

Note that antialiased circles don't have a width, so the final `10` term is lost.